# Flash Card App that allows data tree linking between cards?

Tags: web-apps, data-visualization, data, flashcard, japanese

I'm currently studying Japanese Kanji: I've taken a large list of kanji (2300) and arranged them all into smaller groups with about 4 kanji on average per group, based on their similar looks etc. (This is to help remember the subtle differences between them). These groups are divided by commas and can be put into .csv if needed.

There are several kanji which are in more than one group, which leads me to my question:

What I'm looking for is some kind of app, mobile or desktop, where I can put each group of kanji onto a flash card. Then be able to click a kanji in that group card and be able to spot the other groups it belongs to.

So for example, in the following groups:

Card1: 者考老孝

Card2: 工攻功巧

Card3: 式弐武

Card4: 者著煮箸暑署曙

Card5: 者猪都賭諸儲緒

The kanji 者 appears in 1, 4 and 5. If I were swiping left and right and came to card 1 reviewing the group's kanji, I'd want to see that 者 belongs to other cards, and click 者 to see those cards and navigate directly to them. So it'd resemble something like a tree data structure, with parent and child nodes.

I've been having a hard time finding a flash card app that does this, both in general and in the Japanese Kanji app areas. Even Anki won't do it. Does anyone have any ideas what software would best fit my needs? Even if it comes down to viewing data in a visual tree diagram as if I could see the variables in each "node" (card) of the linked lists, that'd be a good alternative too.

Thanks very much for your help.